# How can I calculate the number of seconds until next Saturday in C++?

Tags: c++, date, time, epoch

I'm trying to make a calculator that will determine the number of seconds until the start of a specific day.

I am currently able to determine the current day & time, but I'm unsure of how to determine the number of seconds until the start of the future day that I want (let's say Saturday for example).

I'm thinking I could calculate how many days apart from Saturday we are and then convert that into seconds, but the issue is that there might be additional time added on (I want to know the time at midnight, start of day).

Anyone know how this would be possible?

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

class DateTime
{
public:
   DateTime();

   DateTime(
      const time_t& specific_datetime);

   const std::string GetWeekDay() const;

   const std::string GetMonth() const;

   int GetDate() const;

   const int GetSecondsUntilNextWeekDay(
      const std::string& day_name) const;

private:

   const int GetWeekDayNumberFromName(
      const std::string& name) const;

   tm m_time;
   const time_t m_datetime;

   DateTime(const DateTime &rhs);
   DateTime &operator=(const DateTime &rhs);
};
```

```
#include "DateTime.h"

DateTime::DateTime() :
   m_datetime(std::time(NULL))
{
   localtime_s(&m_time, &m_datetime);
}

DateTime::DateTime(
   const time_t& specific_datetime) :
   m_datetime(specific_datetime)
{
   localtime_s(&m_time, &m_datetime);
}

const std::string DateTime::GetWeekDay() const
{
   switch (m_time.tm_wday)
   {
   case 0:
      return "Sunday";
   case 1:
      return "Monday";
   case 2:
      return "Tuesday";
   case 3:
      return "Wednesday";
   case 4:
      return "Thursday";
   case 5:
      return "Friday";
   case 6:
      return "Saturday";
   default:
      return "Sunday";
   }
}

const std::string DateTime::GetMonth() const
{
   switch (m_time.tm_mon)
   {
   case 0:
      return "January";
   case 1:
      return "February";
   case 2:
      return "March";
   case 3:
      return "April";
   case 4:
      return "May";
   case 5:
      return "June";
   case 6:
      return "July";
   case 7:
      return "August";
   case 8:
      return "September";
   case 9:
      return "October";
   case 10:
      return "November";
   case 11:
      return "December";
   default:
      return "January";
   }
}

int DateTime::GetDate() const
{
   return m_time.tm_mday;
}

int DateTime::GetYear() const
{
   return 1900 + m_time.tm_year;
}

const int DateTime::GetSecondsUntilNextWeekDay(
   const std::string& day_name) const
{
   // Calculate how many seconds left for today...
   const int todays_hours_left = 23 - m_time.tm_hour;
   const int todays_minutes_left = (todays_hours_left * 60) + (59 - m_time.tm_min);
   const int todays_seconds_left = (todays_minutes_left * 60) + (59 - m_time.tm_sec);
   int overlap_seconds = 0;

   // Calculate how many days until the desired date.
   int current_day_number = m_time.tm_wday;
   const int desired_day_number = GetWeekDayNumberFromName(day_name);

   if (desired_day_number >= 0)
   {
      if (desired_day_number <= current_day_number)
      {
         // Find out how many days left in the week, add them to how many days until the today.
         const int max_day = 6;
         const int days_remaining = max_day - current_day_number;
         overlap_seconds = (days_remaining * 24 * 60 * 60);
         current_day_number = 0;
      }

      const int days_left = desired_day_number - current_day_number;
      const int hours_left = days_left * 24;
      const int minutes_left = hours_left * 60;
      const int seconds_left = (minutes_left * 60) - (86400 - todays_seconds_left) + overlap_seconds;

      return seconds_left;
   }

   return -1;
}

const int DateTime::GetWeekDayNumberFromName(
   const std::string& name) const
{
   if (name == "Sunday")
   {
      return 0;
   }
   else if (name == "Monday")
   {
      return 1;
   }
   else if (name == "Tuesday")
   {
      return 2;
   }
   else if (name == "Wednesday")
   {
      return 3;
   }
   else if (name == "Thursday")
   {
      return 4;
   }
   else if (name == "Friday")
   {
      return 5;
   }
   else if (name == "Saturday")
   {
      return 6;
   }

   return -1;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

#include "DateTime.h"

int main()
{
   DateTime date_time;

   const int seconds = date_time.GetSecondsUntilNextWeekDay("Monday");
   std::cout << "Seconds Till Date: " << seconds;
}
```

I would expect that if I wanted to know how long until the start of Thursday from the current time (9:00 PM on Wednesday) it would return 3 hours or 10800 seconds (either or work).

Answer (score 1):

This question has a couple of subtle issues:

- Is the "start of day" in a specific time zone?  In UTC?

By reading the code in the question, it appears that "start of day" is defined by the computer's local time zone setting.

- Since we are taking time zones into account, I presume we need to also take into account daylight saving.  For example if there is a 1-h "Spring Forward" transition at 2:00 on a specific day, then on that day the elapsed time from 1:00 to 3:00 is 1h, whereas on "normal" days it is 2h.  Unless we intend to count "local seconds" as opposed to "physical seconds".  The question isn't crystal clear on this issue...

I tested the code given in the question, using "America/New_York" as the local time zone with 3 input pairs:

1. Saturday 2019-03-02 22:02:05 EST to Monday 2019-03-04 00:00:00 EST
2. Saturday 2019-03-09 22:02:05 EST to Monday 2019-03-11 00:00:00 EDT
3. Saturday 2019-03-16 22:02:05 EDT to Monday 2019-03-18 00:00:00 EDT

This is computing the time between late Saturday night and the beginning of Monday for 3 weeks in a row, with the middle week straddling a UTC offset change due to daylight saving going into effect.

The code in the question gives 7074s for all input pairs.  In hh:mm:ss format, that is 01:57:54.  That is approximately 1 day off the correct answer, which for the 1st and 3rd input pairs is 93475s, or 1 day and 7075s, or 1 day and 01:57:55.

The correct answer for the second case, because Sunday is only 23 hours long, is 1h less, or 89875s.

I didn't track down all of the issues in the code within the question but there appear to be at least these 3:

1. Off-by-one bug in the number of days computation.
2. Off-by-one bug in the number of seconds computation.
3. Neglect UTC offset changes that may occur in the local time zone.

[Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, time zone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)<sup>1</sup> can be used to correct these issues:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

std::chrono::seconds
GetSecondsUntilNextWeekDay(date::weekday wd,
                           date::sys_seconds tp = 
                      date::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()))
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    auto zone = current_zone();
    zoned_seconds now = {zone, tp};
    auto today_local = floor<days>(now.get_local_time());
    weekday today_wd{today_local};
    auto delta_days = wd - today_wd;
    if (delta_days == days{0} && now.get_local_time() != today_local)
        delta_days += weeks{1};
    zoned_seconds target_date = {zone, today_local + delta_days};
    return target_date.get_sys_time() - now.get_sys_time();
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    zoned_seconds zt{current_zone(), local_days{March/9/2019} + 22h + 2min + 5s};
    std::cout << GetSecondsUntilNextWeekDay(Monday, zt.get_sys_time()) << '\n';
}
```

This code works by creating a `zoned_seconds` for both the input time, and the target time (start of the target weekday as defined by the local time zone).
`zoned_seconds` is a specialization of `zoned_time<Duration>` with seconds-precision.

A `zoned_time` is a pairing of local time point and a `time_zone`.  It can equivalently be thought of as a pairing of a UTC time point and a `time_zone`.  In either case, one can construct using either a `local_time` or a `sys_time` (`sys_time` is UTC), and one can extract both a `local_time` and a `sys_time`, which are related via the `time_zone`.

The `time_zone` in this example is found with `current_zone()` which detects the computer's current local time zone setting.

`now` is a pairing of the input `sys_time` (`sys_seconds` is an alias for seconds-precision `sys_time`), and the computer's current local time zone.

`today_local` is a day-precision `local_time` found by getting `now`'s `local_time` and flooring it to day-precision.

The local `weekday` can be constructed directly from `today_local`.

`delta_days` is the number of days one must add to `today_wd` to reach the target `weekday` of `wd`.  The `weekday` subtraction is circular in nature:  It always results in a number of days in the range [0, 6] and is independent of the underlying encoding of the weekdays.  For example Sunday is always 1 day after Saturday, even if Saturday is encoded as 6 and Sunday as 0.

If the current `weekday` is the same as the target `weekday`, and if this isn't the first second of the target `weekday`, then we want to compute to the start of the same day next week.  Otherwise `now` is the target date and this function will return 0 seconds.

Given the number of days (`delta_days`) and The current day (`today_local`), the target date can be computed with `today_local + delta_days`.  This is a days-precision `local_time` which will implicitly convert to seconds-precision and point to the start of the day.  This is paired with the local time zone to construct `target_date`.

Now that we have `target_date` and `now`, we just have to subtract them to get the desired number of seconds.  There are two ways to do this subtraction:

1. In `local_time`.  This would measure time in "calendrical seconds" as defined by the local `time_zone`.  In this calendar, all days are 24h.
2. In `sys_time`.  This converts to UTC prior to the subtraction, and thus measures "physical seconds".  This detects the 23h Sunday in case 2 above.

Notes:

- The code contains no explicit conversion constants such as 60, 24, or 86400.
- The code does not bother computing the elapsed seconds of the current day.
- The code is independent of the `weekday` encoding, and is thus much simplified.
- The code completely avoids the antiquated C timing API, and is thus much simplified.

As I write this:

```
std::cout << GetSecondsUntilNextWeekDay(Saturday) << '\n';
```

Outputs:

```
128459s
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [Howard Hinnant's time zone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) is now part of the C++20 specification, with minor changes such as putting it into `namespace std::chrono`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
using std::chrono::system_clock;

int main()
{
    std::time_t current = std::time(nullptr);
    tm* timeinfo = localtime(&current);                                      
    int wday=timeinfo->tm_wday;                                             
    int hour=timeinfo->tm_hour;                                             
    int min=timeinfo->tm_min;                                               
    int sec=timeinfo->tm_sec;  

    int seconds_passed = sec + (60 * min) + (60 * 60 * hour);  // get the time in seconds passed after 12 AM  

    // days till next saturday.
    switch (wday)
    {       
        case 1: 
            wday = 5;
            break;
        case 2: 
            wday = 4;
            break;
        case 3:  
            wday = 3;
            break;
        case 4: 
            wday = 2;
            break;
        case 5:
            wday = 1;
            break;
        case 6:
            wday = 7;
            break;
        case 0:
            wday = 6;
        break;
    }

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point t = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point new_t = t + std::chrono::hours(wday * 24);  // get saturdays timestamp

    std::time_t time = system_clock::to_time_t(new_t) - seconds_passed; // subtract seconds_passed from saturdays timestamp

    int seconds = time - current ;  //seconds until next saturday

    std::cout <<"Number of seconds until next saturday "<< seconds <<"\n";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've updated the original question with this solution, I'm not certain if there is an easier way to do this... so I'm open for suggestions.

Here's the added code...

```
const int DateTime::GetSecondsUntilNextWeekDay(
   const std::string& day_name) const
{
   // Calculate how many seconds left for today...
   const int todays_hours_left = 23 - m_time.tm_hour;
   const int todays_minutes_left = (todays_hours_left * 60) + (59 - m_time.tm_min);
   const int todays_seconds_left = (todays_minutes_left * 60) + (59 - m_time.tm_sec);
   int overlap_seconds = 0;

   // Calculate how many days until the desired date.
   int current_day_number = m_time.tm_wday;
   const int desired_day_number = GetWeekDayNumberFromName(day_name);

   if (desired_day_number >= 0)
   {
      if (desired_day_number <= current_day_number)
      {
         // Find out how many days left in the week, add them to how many days until the today.
         const int max_day = 6;
         const int days_remaining = max_day - current_day_number;
         overlap_seconds = (days_remaining * 24 * 60 * 60);
         current_day_number = 0;
      }

      const int days_left = desired_day_number - current_day_number;
      const int hours_left = days_left * 24;
      const int minutes_left = hours_left * 60;
      const int seconds_left = (minutes_left * 60) - (86400 - todays_seconds_left) + overlap_seconds;

      return seconds_left;
   }

   return -1;
}

const int DateTime::GetWeekDayNumberFromName(
   const std::string& name) const
{
   if (name == "Sunday")
   {
      return 0;
   }
   else if (name == "Monday")
   {
      return 1;
   }
   else if (name == "Tuesday")
   {
      return 2;
   }
   else if (name == "Wednesday")
   {
      return 3;
   }
   else if (name == "Thursday")
   {
      return 4;
   }
   else if (name == "Friday")
   {
      return 5;
   }
   else if (name == "Saturday")
   {
      return 6;
   }

   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please just edit this into your actual question. Stack Overflow is not a forum, so adding new "posts" is not how you update things. SO has a question and answer(s), so you've added this as an answer to your question (which obvs isn't correct). You can delete this and simply update your original question.